# Configuring spring to return a static file on a Controller method

Tags: spring-mvc

How do I say to Spring MVC to return a static resource at runtime(in a method)?

Explain better. I configured my application(spring-mvc 3.2.4) to deal with some static resource and to work with two view resolvers, FreeMaker and Json. I wish that in a controller method I would be able to say to spring-mvc that he must take the file in the static resource despite try hadle by one of views resolvers.

My configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxxx", excludeFilters =  @Filter(Configuration.class)})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/app.js").addResourceLocations("/app.js");
    }
    ...
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        // Define the view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();       

        JsonViewResolver jsonViewResolver = new JsonViewResolver();

        FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix("rtl");

        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver);
        resolvers.add(freeMarkerViewResolver);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class JSViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value="*.js")
    public String resolveArquivo(HttpServletRequest request){
        // Here I would be able to say to sprint to return a static resource instead of hadle it with one of the View Resolvers.        
        return request.getRequestURI().replace(request.getContextPath(),"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its would be better if you try to access static and dynamic data seperately as hitting a controller for static data will waste your resources, increase latency.

For eg. if you want to access js from jsp then you can use JSTL  tag library which would dynamically return the output directory from where you can fetch the static resource.

This gives you the flexibility to cache your static resources (Akamei or something  else) or server them from apache instead of tomcat.

If you really want to render your static resource from controller then you need to have an interceptor which could be called before any of the view resolvers which will identify whether the requested resource us static and render accordingly. But this would be invoked for every htttp request which is not desirable.

Comment: Vineet, thank you for your answer.

I'm doing this because I'm trying to generate some dynamic javascript code to remove some boilerplate code that I must duplicate between JS and Java(eg. Models). Because of this, I can't change the place where the browser is trying to get the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how return a static resource in runtime with spring, but I resolved the situation using the old and good Filter.